# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level I do not understand anything

Tags: python, discord.py

I do not understand anything. I already checked everything, in IDLE I translated spaces in tab, through format> tabify region. It still doesn't work. WHAT IS NOT SO

```
File "bot.py", line 365
if if_do==True:
               ^  
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Short code:

```
 if_do = True
                    if patron in ctx.message.author.roles:
                        await ctx.messsage.author.remove_roles(patron) 
                        await ctx.message.channel.send('И патрон потратил...')
                    break
            if if_do==True: 
                await ctx.message.channel.send('Чел, ты...А патрон...')
```

All code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 15, commands.BucketType.user) 
async def shot(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if_do = False
    police = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=867662803968065586)
    armor = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=867692189106044939)
    dead = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=867692254746640394)
    hard_blood = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=867692258760196116)
    easy_blood = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=867692269054459954)
    gun = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=868069389365280818)
    patron = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=868228372222840913)
    if gun in ctx.message.author.roles:
        if patron in ctx.message.author.roles or police in ctx.message.author.roles:
                if member == None:
                    await ctx.message.channel.send('Выстрел в воздух...Бедная птичка..')
                    if patron in ctx.message.author.roles:
                        await ctx.messsage.author.remove_roles(patron)
                        await ctx.message.channel.send('И патрон потратил...')
                else:
                    mention = member.mention
                    veroyatnost = randint(1,10)
                    telo = ['левую ногу','левую руку','правую ногу','правую ногу','живот','плече','грудь']
                    if veroyatnost>6 and veroyatnost<=10:
                        res = 'В {} выстрелили! К счастью пуля не попала в цель.'.format(mention)
                    elif armor in member.roles:
                        res = 'В {} стреляли! К счастью на нем был бронежилет, который больше непригоден...'.format(mention)
                        await member.remove_roles(armor)
                    else:
                        if veroyatnost<3:
                            await member.add_roles(dead)
                            res = 'В {} выстрелили! Рана смертельная, поздравляю, вы умерли.'.format(mention)
                        elif veroyatnost>=3 and veroyatnost<=4 :
                            await member.add_roles(hard_blood)
                            res = 'В {} выстрелили! Ловкое попадание. Тяжелая рана. Выстрел в {}. Боль. '.format(mention,random.choice(telo))
                        elif veroyatnost>4 and veroyatnost <=6:
                            await member.add_roles(easy_blood)
                            res = 'В {} выстрелили! Чудом уклонившись он(а) получил(а) легкое рание в {}'.format(mention,random.choice(telo))
                    await ctx.message.channel.send(res)
                    if_do = True
                    if patron in ctx.message.author.roles:
                        await ctx.messsage.author.remove_roles(patron) 
                        await ctx.message.channel.send('И патрон потратил...')
                    break
            if if_do==True: 
                await ctx.message.channel.send('Чел, ты...А патрон...')
    else:
        await ctx.message.channel.send('Тебе не из чего стрелять!')
```

Comment: The problem is exactly what the message tells you: that `if` statement is indented at a unique level, where the language structure requires it to match something above.  What confuses you about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: A diagrammed version of the indentation of Night Spirit's code. A red line indicates that the line in question does not align to any previous indentation level]

I diagrammed your code. See how the line that's throwing an error doesn't line up with any previous indentations? Python doesn't know what to do with that, so it throws an error. In general, try and make your indentations always the same number of spaces, to avoid this.

Consider these two pieces of code:

```
a = 3
if a < 5:
        if a < 2:
            print("option 1")
        else:
            print("option 2")
```

Here, the "else" is regarding the `if a < 2` statement, so "option 2" will be printed. Compare that to:

```
a = 3
if a < 5:
        if a < 2:
            print("option 1")
else:
    print("option 2")
```

Here, nothing will be printed, because the `else` refers to the `if a < 5` line. Now imagine:

```
a = 3
if a < 5:
        if a < 2:
            print("option 1")
    else:
        print("option 2")
```

Which `if` statement is the `else` in reference to? It's ambiguous, and so python says "fix this!" rather than taking a guess.